# How to generate anagrams from an input string in a short and effective way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a program to generate all potential anagrams of an input string.
>
> For example, the potential anagrams of "biro" are
>
> biro bior brio broi boir bori
> ibro ibor irbo irob iobr iorb
> rbio rboi ribo riob roib robi
> obir obri oibr oirb orbi orib

I couldn't find a specific correction to that question in the forums, so if this is a duplicate please feel free to send me to the topic I should be looking at.

I'm a beginner and I don't know enough about Python yet to use the right functions and methods for this exercise. I came up with that to test something. But it's a total mess and it fails to do the job, don't waste time deciphering it :

```
texte = "biro"
liste = list(texte)
n_liste = []
for itera, f in enumerate(liste) :
   if f == liste[0]:
       n_string = str(liste[itera])+str(liste[(liste.index(f)+1):])
   if f == liste[itera] and (itera >= 1):
       n_string = str(liste[0])+str(liste[liste.index(f)])+str(liste[(liste.index(f)+1):])
   if f == liste[len(liste)-1]:
       n_string = str(liste[0])+str(liste[liste.index(f):])
   n_liste.append(n_string)
print(n_liste)
```

The text to work on should be an input, not a str variable.
Are there any efficient ways to find anagrams of a given string no matter how long it is? (without using libraries)

Comment: `itertools.product`?

Comment: I see "without using libraries", but *with* libraries, the function to use is [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: @gold_cy That doesn't just build anagrams, so you'd need additional filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a recursive generator:

```
def anagrams(S,anagram=""):
   if not S:                    # no more characters,
      yield anagram             # return completed anagram
      return
   for i,c in enumerate(S):     # with each letter at current position
      yield from anagrams(S[:i]+S[i+1:],anagram+c) # add sub-anagrams
```

output:

```
for a in anagrams('biro'): print(a)
biro
bior
brio
broi
boir
bori
ibro
ibor
irbo
irob
iobr
iorb
rbio
rboi
ribo
riob
robi
roib
obir
obri
oibr
oirb
orbi
orib
```

This could also be achieved (returning a list) with an iterative approach where you start out with the original string in a list and progressively expand the list by swapping characters into each position with the characters in the remaining positions.

```
def anagrams(S):
    result = [S]
    for i in range(len(S)):                # position to swap into
        result,partial = [],result
        for p in partial:                  # partially expanded so far
            for j,c in enumerate(p[i:],i): # swap with each remaining char.
                result.append(p[:i]+c+p[i:j]+p[j+1:]) # expanding result
    return result
```

Comment: A compact solution. Perhaps too compact; the variable names could be more informative and the if-statement split into several lines.

Comment: @md2perpe But then how would I have recognized that it's Alain before seeing the name? :-) (but I agree, and the style is why I don't upvote)

Comment: Happy to be recognized, even if it is from my bad habits :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def anagrams(values):
    result = []

    if len(values) == 0:
        return [""]

    for first_index in range(len(values)):
        first = values[first_index]
        rest  = values[:first_index] + values[first_index+1:]
        for rest_permutation in anagrams(rest):
            result.append(first + rest_permutation)

    return result

# Example
print(anagrams("biro"))
```

Comment: Could have avoided the usage of "all" as a variable name since it is a built-in function

Signature: all(iterable, /)
Docstring:
Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.

If the iterable is empty, return True.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

Comment: @Parthi. Changed `all` to `result`.

Comment: @KellyBundy. Fixed. It was a rest from using lists internally.